# How to configure WS2812B adressable LED strip with RPI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, smart-lights, lighting

I hope this is correct place to answer this kind of question. 
I know this might be a basic question and yes there are a lot of tutorial out there.

**Purpose:** To make dynamic ambilight effect behind my TV.

I was learning from a following tutorial [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J26oYlKyq7Q&t=1477s)
I ordered a 5 meter WS2812B adressable LED strip.
Connected it to 5V 10A power supply but LED did not glow.
Later I tried to connect GPIO pin of Rpi 4 GPIO 18 pin to LED Din Pin as shown in youtube video and tried to configure it via hyperbian installed in rpi but nothing happened.

**Issue:**
Just 4-5 led lights up (Position of LEDS that Lights up -> 4th, 7th, last 2nd and last 6th).
Also tried to change only these 4-5 led pins which were glowing just to try maybe it may change colours but it didn't.

**Solution/Answers needed:**
Is my LED strip broken?.
I kept LEDs on for kinda 30 minutes and there wasn't any burning smell or anything so I guess power supply is good.
Am I doing something wrong or if I don't know how to address it?

**What I tried?**
I connected a wire to gpio 18 of RPi and tried connecting Din slot of led and result is some  of the non lightning LED lights up with some different colours till I stop the power supply. After restarting power supply, again those 4 leds only glow.. So these LEDs are working.

**Forgot to mention**

Connected rpi with usb type c from another 5V charger

Please help me.

**IMAGES**

1. THE LED RESULT I GET. No change even I add/remove GPIO data Pin.
   [image: The Led Result I get]
2. MY LED STRIP 
   [image: My Led Strip]
3. I drawn my connection on the page to understand better. Hope everyone can read it.
   [image: Connection Drawn]

Comment: @jsotola I connected ground i.e 6th pin(3 pins before gpio18) of rpi with led strip ground. Nothings changing.

Comment: then the LED strip or the software or the GPIO pin or wiring are suspect ... which LED strip are you using? ... please add a picture of the connections

Comment: @jsotola Please wait, I am uploading right now. Give me 2 minutes. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: @jsotola LED I am using ws2812b- I mentioned in question above. I checked Gpio pin. There was little spark and change in colour of some LED when I directly connected that pin to some LEDs in between which were off. So I guess GPIO pin has power too. Wiring, can you give me any diagram on how it is done? Any link of it?

Comment: What are you actually using to control the LEDs? WS2812 LED strips use a orrery weird variable pulse protocol which requires pretty precise timings. APA102 LEDs are much easier to use as they use standard SPI. In both cases you send a string of settings for each LED. The first LED takes the first set of RGB settings and then forwards the rest to the next LED, and so on.

Comment: @jcaron Using Rpi to control LEDs I guess. In tutorials this same model ws2812b is used so I am using this too.

Comment: But what are you using on the RPi to do that? You need some software that will send the right signals on that GPIO to tell each LED what colour you want it to display…

Comment: @jcaron oh ya, hyperbian. But even I don't connect rpi, the leds behave and give result like above in image.